# how to swap stacks element in java

Tags: java

I want to do a swap to the two tops element in a stack 
I tried, but can not figure it out

```
public void swap(){

 T temp=stack[topIndex];
 stack[topIndex]=stack[stack.length-1];
 stack[stack.length-1]=temp;


 }
```

topindex is already defined in superclass

Comment: Why not just pop off two elements, then push them back on in the opposite order?

Comment: You are incorrectly referring the 2nd top element using stack.length -  1, try stack.length -2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are mixing up `topIndex` with `stack.length`

It seems you are using an array to implement a stack. In this case the code to swap two top elements is the same as for swapping two elements in an array:

```
T temp = stack[topIndex];
stack[topIndex] = stack[topIndex - 1];
stack[topIndex - 1] = temp;
```

You can implement this also popping two elements and pushing them back in the opposite order. Adding a check if you have at least two elements is also a good idea.

Comment: thank you , I'm trying to test it and I made test class, but I do not know how to create stack

Comment: It is probably: `FStack<String> s = new FStack<String>("LKJH");`. Depends on how you defined it. Anyway, if you have other question that are not related the best thing is to ask a new question. Also, consider accepting the answer that helped you the most (green tick beside the answer). That helps other users that have the same problem of yours

Answer (score 2):

As @ColonelThirtyTwo mentioned in the comments,

```
if(stack.size() >= 2)
{
    T first = stack.pop();
    T second = stack.pop();
    stack.push(first);
    stack.push(second);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this code does not work. Read the OP's code more carefully.